# Asterisk - переадресация вызовов

Tags: asterisk, sip, voip

Asterisk связан с миром через GSM-шлюз. К нему подключен SIP телефон и софтофон на отдельной машине. (Asterisk 11.20, CentOS 6.5)

Есть два экстеншна

exten => _79XXXXXXXXX,1,Answer()
 same => n,Dial(dongle/dongle0/+${EXTEN}, 20)
 same => n,Hangup()

exten => 200,1,Answer()
 same => n,Dial(dongle/dongle0/+79041589488, 20)
 same => n,Hangup()

Первый работает. Как я понял какой номер набрали на трубке SIP'а или софтофона, таким и будет экстеншн, на такой номер и звонить через GSM.
Второй не работает, а нужен он для того, что бы не вбивать 11 значный, а вбить короткий, в пределах фиса. Теоретически ведь я никаких правил не нарушаю вводя новый экстеншн который до этого нигде и никак не был задействован и вешая на него вызов на определенный номер?
В CLI при этом тихо, никаких сообщений, в трубке - "заданый номер не доступен". Если заменить 200 на 101 он позвонит в экстренную пожарную службу, значит пытается звонить на номер экстеншна, а не на номер в Dial.
Та же ситуация при звонках с внутреннего на внутренний

[sip.zoiper2]    ;Софтофон
username = sip.zoiper2
secret = my_pass234
context = dongle-incoming
type = friend
host = dynamic
callerid = 100

exten => 100,1,Answer()
 same => n,Dial(SIP/sip.zoiper2, 20)
 same => n,Hangup()

То же самое, набираю на SIP'e 100 и набранный номер не доступен. Позвонить на него можно только если экстеншн +1234567890, а с него только если в Dial(...+${EXTEN})

Ну и переадресация

exten => +1234567890,1,Answer()
 same => 2,Dial(SIP/tech, 20)   ;Звонок на SIP телефон (из GSM шлюза)
 same => 3,Dial(dongle/dongle0/+79248275787, 20)   ;Переадресация начальнику тех.отдела
 same => n,Hangup()

На SIP звонок идет, как только проходит 20 секунд:
**WARNING [dongle0] Request to call on device which can not make call at this moment**
**WARNING nable to create channel of type 'dongle' (cause 44 - Requested channel not available)**

Переадресация и вообще инфа о экстеншнах взята отседова: [Asterisk Dialplan - extensions.conf](http://asterisk-pbx.ru/wiki/asterisk/dialplan)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас случайно GSM шлюз не подвисает на звонке? Такое чувство, что у него канал не освобождается после предыдущего звонка (последний WARNING). Для вывода более подробной информации в консоли введите **core set verbose 3** После всех манипуляций тоже, только на конце 0

Comment: Да нет, никаких подвисаний или иных косяков не замечено.

Comment: Asterisk голый или есть панели для настройки типа FreePBX? context = dongle-incoming для софтфона и телефона такой же? exten прописаны все в этом же контексте?

Comment: По поводу второй части, звонок приходит от GSM шлюза через транк dongle/dongle0, который похоже является одноканальным. И звонок на номер +79248275787 вы пытаетесь отправить через этот же транк, но канал уже занят, вот и идет отбой.

Comment: Да, точно, переадресация на другой внутренний номер проходит. В этом случае если шлюз одноканальный никак не выкрутишься кроме как установки второго шлюза?

Comment: Только использовать другой канал. Не обязательно шлюз, можете подключиться к VoIP оператору.

Comment: Сделали другой канал, вроде работает)